# Inserting into DB2 fom SAS dataset with passthrough SQL

Tags: sas, timestamp, db2, proc-sql, pass-through

I'm still new to SAS and DB2. I have a DB2 Table with a column that stores values encoded as timestamps. I'm trying to load data onto this column from a SAS data set in my Work directory. Some of these timestamps, however, correspond to dates before 01-01-1582 and can not be stored as datetime values in SAS. They are instead stored as strings.

This means that if I want to load these values onto the DB2 table I must first convert them to timestamp with the TIMESTAMP() DB2 function, which, as far as I know, requires passthrough SQL with an execute statement (as opposed to the SAS ACCESS libname method). For instance, in order to write a single value I do the following:

```
PROC SQL;
    connect to db2 (user = xxxx database = xxxx password = xxxx);
    execute (insert into xxxx.xxxx (var) values (TIMESTAMP('0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000'))) by db2;
    disconnect from db2;
quit;
```

How can I achieve this for all values in the source data set? A select ... from statement inside the execute command doesn't work because as far as I know I can't reference the SAS Work directory from within the DB2 connection.

Ultimately I could write a macro that executes the PROC SQL block above and call it from within a data step for every observation but I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this. Changing the types of the variables is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convoluted way of working around that would be to use `call execute`:

```
data _null_;
set sas_table;
call execute("PROC SQL;
              connect to db2 (user = xxxx database = xxxx password = xxxx);
              execute (
                 insert into xxxx.xxxx (var)
                 values (TIMESTAMP('"||strip(dt_string)||"'))
                ) by db2;
              disconnect from db2;
              quit;");
run;
```

Where `sas_table` is your SAS dataset containing the datetime values stored as strings and in a variable called `dt_string`.

What happens here is that, for each observation in a dataset, SAS will execute the argument of the `execute` call routine, each time with the current value of `dt_string`.

Another method using macros instead of call execute to do essentially the same thing:

```
%macro insert_timestamp;
  %let refid = %sysfunc(open(sas_table));
  %let refrc = %sysfunc(fetch(&refid.));
  %do %while(not &refrc.);
    %let var = %sysfunc(getvarc(&refid.,%sysfunc(varnum(&refid.,dt_string))));

    PROC SQL;
      connect to db2 (user = xxxx database = xxxx password = xxxx);
      execute (insert into xxxx.xxxx (var) values (TIMESTAMP(%str(%')&var.%str(%')))) by db2;
     disconnect from db2;
    quit;

    %let refrc = %sysfunc(fetch(&refid.));
  %end;
  %let refid = %sysfunc(close(&refid.));
%mend;
%insert_timestamp;
```

**EDIT**: I guess you could also load the table as-is in DB2 using SAS/ACCESS and then convert the strings to timestamp with sql pass-through. Something like

```
libname lib db2 database=xxxx schema=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx;
data lib.temp;
set sas_table;
run;
PROC SQL;
    connect to db2 (user = xxxx database = xxxx password = xxxx);
    execute (create table xxxx.xxxx (var TIMESTAMP)) by db2;
    execute (insert into xxxx.xxxx select TIMESTAMP(dt_string) from xxxx.temp) by db2;
    execute (drop table xxxx.temp) by db2;
    disconnect from db2;
quit;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. That was also my idea when I talked about calling the proc sql withing a data step. I'm wondering though: Why use ' " in the TIMESTAMP() call?

Comment: You're welcome. I cannot tell if your question pertains to single or double quotes. If singles, well, in your code, the timestamp value is enclosed in single quotes; so the single quotes here are so that the resolved value of `dt_string` is also enclosed in single quotes in the called query. If doubles, well, I don't _use_ them in the `timestamp` call. I'm merely closing the string up to this point before concatenating with the value of `dt_string`.

Comment: It wasn't working for me before because I was trying with TIMESTAMP(&var) and TIMESTAMP("&var"). It did however work when I tried your TIMESTAMP(%str(%')&var.%str(%')). Thanks once again for that! I assume this works because the DB2 requires single quotes...is that the case? Finally, is it then safe to conclude that this can't be done with a "simple" proc sql?

Comment: @MarcoLeal Yes, DB2 (and most other SQL implementations) requires single quotes for string literals. Double quotes specifie members like variable names, table names, etc... I edited my answer to add another option that goes a different way.